# How to upload video on instagram in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, instagram

I am developing an application which is using instagram.

I have encountered a problem while uploading video on instagram.

Please tell me if any demo or sample or tutorial is available for uploading video on instagram.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Instagram Media Endpoints](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/)

> At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a
>   conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons:
>
> Instagram is about your life on the go – we hope to encourage photos
>   from within the app. However, in the future we may give whitelist
>   access to individual apps on a case by case basis.
>
> We want to fight spam & low quality photos. Once we allow uploading from other sources,
>   it's harder to control what comes into the Instagram ecosystem. All
>   this being said, we're working on ways to ensure users have a
>   consistent and high-quality experience on our platform.

Comment: is  there any other way to do it !!!!!!

Comment: Best you can do is to direct the user to the instagram app once you have the media ready. http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/

Comment: Thanks a lot for iPhone hooks!!!

Comment: Is it possible to send a video to the Instagram app using hooks?

Comment: iPhone app Cinamatic let users to upload video to iPhone apparently via HTTP POST + Instagram oAuth API.